# Delete Table Row from nested <ul> list item

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a html table that has an `<ul>` in it. The table is bound by a knockout view model.

When I click on the `TEST` text I would like remove the `<tr>` that the clicked TEST text is in, from the `table`. I have it now so when I click on `REMOVE` it removes the `<tr>` but I need it so when I click on the `TEST` it removes the `<tr>`. Help is greatly appreciated!

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lhalverson/5Lfsba0f/) with it, and/or see code snippet below.

**VIEW MODEL**

```js
var rowModel = function(id, list) {
  this.uid = ko.observable(id);
  this.myList = ko.observableArray(list);
};

function myViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.myArr = ko.observableArray([
    new rowModel(1, ["str1", "str2", "str3"]),
    new rowModel(2, ["str1", "str2"]),
    new rowModel(3, ["str1"])
  ]);

  //this.myList = ko.observableArray();

  self.removeItem = function(rowItem) {
    self.myArr.remove(rowItem);

  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: myArr">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: uid"></td>
      <td>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: myList">
          <li><span data-bind="text: $data"></span>  <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parents[1].removeItem">TEST</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeItem">REMOVE</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: simple . right now your are removing from `self.myArr` which is wrong you have to remove from `myList` so try this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/23037/ . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the context of the data for the `TEST` link is a `myList` item, not a `myArr` item.  Your `removeItem()` function is expecting a `myList` item.  You need to pass the data from the (in this case) parent context.  You can use `$parentContext.$data` or simply `$parent`.

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: myList">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: function () { $root.removeItem($parent); }">TEST</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! I knew it had to do with context, I just didn't know how to get around it!